# How to pass arguments to IPhone "Run Script over SSH"?

Tags: iphone, ssh, shortcut, x11-forwarding

I'm running a Python script on my local computer using the Shortcuts app from my phone (this works perfectly well and returns data to my phone). I also want the script to display a web browser on the local computer. The code for this is simple:

```
import webbrowser
import sys
print("This print statement is shown on my phone")
webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe%s').open(str(sys.argv)) # works locally but not over ssh
print("This print statement is also shown on my phone")
```

But to make SSH display I'm confident that I would need the ssh -X or -Y argument which cannot be passed into the shortcuts app.
I can see two solutions which might work but I haven't been able to find

1. There is an equivalent argument to -X or -Y which can be passed in the main body of text for the ssh command
2. There is a way to pass arguments to the shortcut app

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand you correctly.

But, if you ask how to include parameters in your ssh that are attributed to the script you call. I made an example triggering a bash script through ssh, supplied with params.

```
# some variables
X="True"
Y="False"
Z="True"
```

```
# bash script 
# echo supplied parameters 
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

```
# ssh command 
sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@host "bash -s" < /home/user/sc.sh "$X $Y $Z"
```